# D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0 comes and stuck the application

Tags: android, android-typeface

[image: setTypeface with style : 0 error]

When I run the my application it was stuck so I check the Loccat, Its seems
setTypeface with style : 0 error looping.

Comment: `D/` means it is a debug messages. This is not a error.

Comment: Yes, But it run over over time then application memory allocation gone high then application sucked and crashed

Comment: share the error then...

Comment: Application sucked and prompt a  message "Do you want to stop or wait application"

Answer (score 1):

This comes from calls to

`view.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT,0)` or `view.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT,Typeface.NORMAL)`

I believe you can safely change the calls to (omit the second parameter)
`view.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT)`
(view being a TextView)

Galaxy 7 DUOS (SM-G920FD), Android 7.0

Comment: I don't set the typeface anywhere in my app and it still displays these logs, ONLY on samsung device (Galaxy Tab S2)